# Ubuntu 15.04 with Kubuntu Plasma Desktop not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upstart, 15.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04 today. The Laptop booted fine. However, after that I also installed Kubuntu Plasma Desktop from the Ubuntu Software Center.

On booting default “Ubuntu” I get a black blank screen and the Laptop does not complete booting. A mouse pointer can be seen & moved but the Laptop needs a hard reset. However, it boots properly with “Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-15 (recovery mode)” as well as “Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (upstart)” when those options are chosen from the GRUB.

I installed GRUB Customizer & have moved the “Ubuntu, with Linux 3.19.0-15-generic (upstart)” right on top. So the laptop boots alright but I feel this may be a temporary fix before the next kernel update.

I also have Windows 10 booting from the same SSD. The GRUB gives a selection of Windows (on choosing this one can chose Windows 10 (on the same SSD or Window 8.1 on the original HDD that shipped with the Laptop)) & Ubuntu 14.10 (on the original HDD).

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: same problem here. after console login, message with **readonly filesystem** appears.

Comment: I apparently having a similar problem, but I am using Virtualbox VMs. The problem you're describing occurred when I upgraded a Kubuntu VM to 15.04. However, when I install Kubuntu 15.04 from scratch the plasma desktop works just fine.

Comment: Same problem here with a Kubuntu. The uuids in /etc/fstab were wrong for the / and swap partitions, preventing the computer from booting. Booting using the upstart option in grub worked fine strangely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT with more details:
My problem was incorrect device uuids in file **/etc/fstab**.
(the red one is incorrect,the green one added by me and the red one is commented out)
[image]

After correcting the uuids in **/etc/fstab** for **/** and **swap** (with infos from **blkid**), it works for me!

[image]

Comment: Wow Ben, I'm sorry I could not get a word of that tech stuff (uuids in fstab & blkid). I'm not very IT savvy. If its possible  could you walk me through?

Comment: in very short: see /etc/fstab file. compare uuids in this file with uuids from **sudo blkid**. if you still have problems, i will edit my answer with more details.

Comment: Yes, Ben I did try & poke around at the Home folder even after clicking view Hidden Files. Unfortunately, could not get to those files. Please could you elaborate. I greatly appreciate your help & am grateful.

Comment: see my edited answer. file **fstab** is **not** in your home-folder (it's in /etc).You need root/sudo rights to edit this file.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ben. I find it a bit too technical. Since the Laptop is booting fine I will not consider it broken so won't fix it. I will revert to this if an update/upgrade breaks it. Thanks again.