# Ubuntu 15.04. Problem booting with systemd

Tags: boot, 15.04, systemd

I just upgraded Ubuntu 14.10 to 15.04. When booting system with **systemd** it only gets to login screen. After login following message is printed:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: 33:
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-fsck-at-reboot: cannot create
/var/lib/update-notifier/fsck-at-reboot: Read-only file system
```

When I change kernel parameter `ro` to `rw` system boots normally.

Booting with `upstart` also works. So seems it's specific to `systemd` problem.

**UPDATE**:
As Ben pointed in comments problem was caused by incorrect UUIDs for partitions in `\etc\fstab` file. Command to check valid UUIDs `ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/*`.

Comment: i have the same problem, where did you change the parameter (in fstab?)?

Comment: Hi.  You can change parameter in bootloader's select screen.  Press `e` and go to line started with `linux` there will be `ro` parameter change that to `rw`. This change will be in effect only for one boot. To change it permanently you need to modify `ro` to `rw` in `\etc\grub.d\10_linux` file. But this is unrecommended practice. Better you can change `systemd` to `upstart` as default service manager: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart

Comment: thanks.my problem was incorrect uuids in fstab.after correcting uuids, it works!

Comment: thanks for pointing to that! i checked and indeed UUIDs was incorrect. Solved my problem.

Comment: i do not know why my answer was deleted?! this makes it by far more complicated to get the answer...

Comment: see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/613818/358044