# Just upgraded to 15.04 and i'm crashing at the login screen

Tags: login, login-screen, crash, 15.04

I just attempted an upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04, the upgrade completed and i get as far as the login screen but when i input my password the screen blacks out flashes a bunch of text that i haven't been able to read yet and takes me back to the login screen. Can someone help me fix this issue or instruct me as to how i can find more information about it. A cursory google search has yielded  nothing so far. Many thanks in advanced and i'm sorry i have no more information than this i am not well versed in the more advanced applications of ubuntu.

Comment: You can use lightdm-gtk-greeter or gdm until update or try Reset your User Profile in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have similar problem to yours: [Ubuntu 15.04. Problem booting with systemd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613334/ubuntu-15-04-problem-booting-with-systemd)

If that's the case in bootloader's select screen select line `Advanced Options for Ubuntu` and then load option with `upstart`.

If that works you can set `upstart` as your default service manager: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers#Permanent_switch_back_to_upstart

Comment: i will try that and report back, thanks so much :)