# Error while starting ubuntu 15.04

Tags: kernel, btrfs

After i have upgraded my Dell Latitude E5540 to Ubuntu 15.04 i have the following upon booting up !

```
Scanning for Btrfs filesystem

[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
See "systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service" for details.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Start NTP daemon.
See "systemctl status ntp.service" for details.
mcc0: Unknown controller version (3)You may experience problems
```

What should i do ?

Comment: i had similar problems....see here: http://askubuntu.com/a/613818/358044 (maybe it helps)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

Grab yourself an install disk, I used an Arch Linux iso.
Boot into it and then use "gdisk /dev/sda" (assuming sda is the drive with btrfs partition).
Find the partition number of btrfs drive using the argument "p".

Close gdisk with "q".

Now for the easy part.
Type "btrfsck --repair /dev/sda[partition-no. from earlier]"

This is a kernel bug with btrfs and has been mentioned on many forums, so your not alone in this.

What happens is if your laptop does an unclean boot, the drive won't mount.
This fixes that.

Hope this helps,

Josh